# How or where do I get a list of all \d commands in postgres interactive temrinal (psql)?

Tags: postgresql

I once saw a nice website that showed the list of all `\d` commands, such as `\dt` for all tables and `\df` for functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `\?`?  Gives you the full list right there in your console.

Comment: Lol that was the answer I was looking for. I knew my question was stupid but I still didn't know the answer. Thanks for the response.